# radio button check doesnt work with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hello I am testing radio buttons on my page but it doesn't work correctly else why not go into else if block?
uncheck works but not when you select a radio button

JQuery Code

```js
$("#s1").click(function () {
      if ($("input[name=test]").prop("checked", false)) {
        alert("Lütfen Seçin");
      } else if ($("input[name=test]:checked").val() == "dunya") {
        var x = parseInt($("#testt").text());
        $.ajax({
          url: "test.php",
          data: { get_data: x },
          type: "post",
          success: function (e) {
            alert("Tebrikler Doğru cevapladınız ve +10 puan kazandınız");
            $("#testt").text(e);
          },
        });
      } else {
        alert("Yanlış Cevap Verdiniz Tekrar Kontrol Edin");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="a" name="test" value="dunya">
<input type="radio" id="b" name="test" value="print">
<input type="radio" id="c" name="test" value="sayi">
<input type="button" value="Kontrol Et" class="first_btn" id="s1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for the wrong values in the first if statement, and it will always come true what you should be checking for is the checked `radio` button of test `input`, not the `props` of the whole radio button set:

```
$("input[name=test]:checked").val()
```

This is how it should look like:

```js
$("#s1").click(function () {
  if ($("input[name=test]:checked").val() === "sayi") {
    console.log("INSIDE sayi check statement");
    alert("Lütfen Seçin");
  } else if ($("input[name=test]:checked").val() === "dunya") {
    console.log("INSIDE dunya check statement");
    var x = parseInt($("#testt").text());
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      data: { get_data: x },
      type: "post",
      success: function (e) {
        alert("Tebrikler Doğru cevapladınız ve +10 puan kazandınız");
        $("#testt").text(e);
      },
    });
  } else {
    console.log("INSIDE print check statement");
    alert("Yanlış Cevap Verdiniz Tekrar Kontrol Edin");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="a" name="test" value="dunya">
<input type="radio" id="b" name="test" value="print">
<input type="radio" id="c" name="test" value="sayi">
<input type="button" value="Kontrol Et" class="first_btn" id="s1">
```

for validation and checking if user selected one input, you can do something like this:

```js
$("#s1").click(function () {
  // Here we are checkinig if any radio button is selected.
  if($("input[name=test]:checked").val() === undefined) {
    alert('PLEASE SELECT A VALUE');
    return ;
  }
  
  if ($("input[name=test]:checked").val() === "sayi") {
    console.log("INSIDE sayi check statement");
    alert("Lütfen Seçin");
  } else if ($("input[name=test]:checked").val() === "dunya") {
    console.log("INSIDE dunya check statement");
    var x = parseInt($("#testt").text());
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      data: { get_data: x },
      type: "post",
      success: function (e) {
        alert("Tebrikler Doğru cevapladınız ve +10 puan kazandınız");
        $("#testt").text(e);
      },
    });
  } else {
    console.log("INSIDE print check statement");
    alert("Yanlış Cevap Verdiniz Tekrar Kontrol Edin");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="a" name="test" value="dunya">
<input type="radio" id="b" name="test" value="print">
<input type="radio" id="c" name="test" value="sayi">
<input type="button" value="Kontrol Et" class="first_btn" id="s1">
```

Comment: What should I do if the user clicks the button without selecting a radio button?

Comment: You can add an if statement to check there is a selected value for the radio input.

Comment: @SkyForest, I updated my snippet to include a check for user input, please consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find my answer useful :)